# Angularjs css different animations for showing and hiding

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using Angularjs for my project and I'm trying to animate cards loading and exiting the screen. Here is what I have so far, the only problem is that cards have the same animation when entering the page and exiting. Is there a way to have a different animations for showing and hiding.

```
card.ng-enter, 
card.ng-leave { 
    -webkit-transition: 400ms ease-in all;
    -moz-transition: 400ms ease-in all;
    -ms-transition: 400ms ease-in all;
    -o-transition: 400ms ease-in all;
    transition: 400ms ease-in all;

    position: relative;
    display: block;  
} 

card.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
card.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,0,1);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1,0,1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1,0,1);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1,0,1);
}

card.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
card.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}
```

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Add a [mcve] please. And remove prefixes - they are not nmedded for most browsers, but make an example mauch larger.

Comment: I meant example with minimal angular application, so that it can be run.